How to update properties (rewriteRuleSets) via bicep for existing resource (app gateway)
I want to update rewriteRuleSets for existing app gate way. How to update an existing resource via bicep
I'm a beginer in this field so If possible, please give me an example
resource appGateWay 'Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways@2024-01-01' existing = {
  name: 'existing-agw'
  scope: resourceGroup('preac_RG')
}

resource updatedAppGateWay 'Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways@2024-01-01' = {
  name: 'existing-agw'
  location: 'West Europe'
  properties: {
    rewriteRuleSets: [
      {
        // id: ''
        name: 'cors-test'
        properties: {
          rewriteRules: [
            {
              actionSet: {
                requestHeaderConfigurations: [
                  {
                    headerName: 'Access-Control-Request-Headers'
                    headerValue: '*'
                  }
                ]
                responseHeaderConfigurations: [
                  {
                    headerName: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
                    headerValue: '*'
                  }
                ]
              }
              conditions: [{

              }]
              name: 'test'
              ruleSequence: 5
            }            
          ]
        }
      }
    ]   
  }

}

I want to add new rewriterule

Do you want to add a new ruleset 'test' to the existing app gateway which already has a ruleset named 'some-other-name'?

I want to add new rule set

Bicep is a declarative language, so it does not support adding a property like a ruleset. There are exceptions, but not in your case.
Instead, you must declare the entire App Gateway resource (like in your second block), including IP configurations, tier, etc. The Bicep engine will convert the code to the ARM template and deploy it to Azure. If the App Gateway does exist, it will be updated; if not - it will be created.
The keyword existing is used to reference a resource, grab its properties, or link with another resource (for example, to add an App Service to the existing App Service Plan). From what I see, you don't need to use it.
While populating all properties of App Gateway is time-consuming, you may also check out and use the respective Azure Verified Module.
Also, you may consider using azure cli command to add a ruleset. That's what I'd do in real life.
